# Убрать отступы между блоками div

Tags: html, css

Здравствуйте. Есть обыкновенные div блоки с фиксированной шириной и высотой. Не понятно откуда между ними есть небольшой отступ. Мне нужно либо сделать так чтобы после самого последнего блока не было пустого пространства. Либо вообще убрать эти отступы, но самое главное чтобы после последнего не было пустого места, чтобы было по самому краю.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.catalog_index {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background: #000;
  width: 1200px;
}

.catalog_index .tile {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 236px;
  height: 250px;
  background: red;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-left: 0;
  margin-right: 0;
  border: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="catalog_index">
  <div class="tile">
    <div class="name">Двери межкомнатные</div>
  </div>
  <div class="tile">
    <div class="name">Двери входные</div>
  </div>
  <div class="tile">
    <div class="name">Двери для бани и сауны</div>
  </div>
  <div class="tile">
    <div class="name">Дверная фурнитура</div>
  </div>
  <div class="tile">
    <div class="name">Козырьки, погонаж, арки</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Буду благодарен за помощь!
P.S. должно быть 4 плитки в ряд.

Comment: это пробелы между инлайн-блоками

Comment: @humster_spb и как быть с ними?

Comment: Можно воспользоваться [flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) ну или примерно [вот так](https://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/)

Comment: @Денис, как вариант - закомментировать (Alexander Grushko уже дал ответ)

Answer (score 0):

У вас пробелы между inline-блоками. Как вариант - закомментировать их

```css
* {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
}

.catalog_index {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background: #000;
  width: 1180px;
}

.catalog_index .tile {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 236px;
  height: 250px;
  background: red;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-left: 0;
  margin-right: 0;
  border: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="catalog_index">
  <div class="tile">
    <div class="name">Двери межкомнатные</div>
  </div><!--
  --><div class="tile">
    <div class="name">Двери входные</div>
  </div><!--
  --><div class="tile">
    <div class="name">Двери для бани и сауны</div>
  </div><!--
  --><div class="tile">
    <div class="name">Дверная фурнитура</div>
  </div><!--
  --><div class="tile">
    <div class="name">Козырьки, погонаж, арки</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -2):

У элементов с `inline-block` учитывается `font-size`. Это как расстояние между буквами, а точнее это символы пробелов между блоками из-за переноса. Если родителю задать `font-size: 0;`, то расстояние соответственно равно 0 и блоки прижимаются друг к другу, но в таком случае блокам или элементам внутри блоков надо незабыть задать `font-size` нужного размера чтобы видеть текст.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.catalog_index {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background: #000;
  width: 1200px;
  font-size: 0;
}

.catalog_index .tile {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 236px;
  height: 250px;
  background: red;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-left: 0;
  margin-right: 0;
  border: 0;
  font-size: 14px;
}
```

```html
<div class="catalog_index">
  <div class="tile">
    <div class="name">Двери межкомнатные</div>
  </div>
  <div class="tile">
    <div class="name">Двери входные</div>
  </div>
  <div class="tile">
    <div class="name">Двери для бани и сауны</div>
  </div>
  <div class="tile">
    <div class="name">Дверная фурнитура</div>
  </div>
  <div class="tile">
    <div class="name">Козырьки, погонаж, арки</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Кроме того можно решить задачу при помощи `float` или `flexbox`, они заставят элементы прижаться друг к другу.